# rx-android (or rx-java) with refreshlayout

Tags: android, rx-java, swiperefreshlayout, rx-android

I'm using a swiperefreshlayout `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`, and using rxjava to query to server every time a swipe happens. My code is like below, I have to create duplicate observable and subscriber inside the `OnRefreshListener` for them to get called, which looks quite bad due to code duplication. If I use the original ones (declared outside), then the subscriber is never returned (no `onNext`, `onError`, `onCompleted` triggered). What am I missing with RxJava in this case?

```
Subscriber<ListVerifyResponseWrapper> subscriber = new Subscriber<ListVerifyResponseWrapper>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "completed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.An_error_has_occured), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ListVerifyResponseWrapper listVerifyResponseWrapper) {
                changeViewStateAccordingToResult(listVerifyResponseWrapper);

            }
        };


        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                Observable<ListVerifyResponseWrapper> observableDuplicate = RestClient.getInstance().getRestApi().getListVerifyRequestDetail(model);

                final Subscriber<ListVerifyResponseWrapper> subscriberDuplicate = new Subscriber<ListVerifyResponseWrapper>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        LogUtils.LOGD(TAG, "completed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.An_error_has_occured), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ListVerifyResponseWrapper listVerifyResponseWrapper) {
                        changeViewStateAccordingToResult(listVerifyResponseWrapper);

                    }
                };

                observableDuplicate.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(subscriberDuplicate);
            }
        });

        observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).subscribe(subscriber);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I solved it by chaining

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

right before the final subscriber. Apparently you have to make sure that stuff concerning the UI is done on the UI thread

Answer (score 0):

On top of [Johnnycube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460378/johnnycube)'s answer (which is correct), I suggest you to use

```
subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

which is meant for processing callbacks, amongst other things.